# I must be honest, you will die

Tags: riddle

> I kill none.
>
> I slay all.
>
> I eat those who have none.
>
> I must be honest, you will die.
>
> To my claws,
>
> you reach nigh.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Money/poverty

kill none.

> It does not hurt you physically

I slay all.

> Money effects everyone and anyone who has poverty is effected.

I eat those who have none.

> Poverty eats those who have no money.

I must be honest, you will die.

> Maybe, you will go through struggles?

To my claws,

> To be a slave just to have money.

you reach nigh.

> You may never be happy with the amount of money you have?

Answer (score 0):

You are a:

> funny joke that is mean

I kill none.

> the sting of a joke cannot kill you.

I slay all.

> 'slay' is used to indicate a joke impressed

I eat those who have none.

> those who have no sense of humor can be devoured by a joke; they have no defense.

I must be honest, you will die.

> you will die laughing

To my claws, you reach nigh.

> once a mean joke has impressed its audience, blood is in the water, and the audience wants nothing more than to see more blood-letting.